# How to center a background tile?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a tiled background for a `match_parent`-wide container, where the tile is repeated from the parent's center, not from its left edge. I want this in order for the background to always appear centered regardless of screen width.

I noticed that Android's `BitmapDrawable` has a `gravity` attribute, but it seems to have no effect when `tileMode` is set to `repeat` or `mirror`. I would have expected that the bitmap is first centered in its container, then repeated outwards from the center point. Instead, it's still left-aligned and then repeated, resulting in the first tile always be fully visible but the last tile being cut off unless the screen width is a multiple of the tile's width.

UPDATE: Just noticed, "Gravity is ignored when the tile mode is enabled." (tileMode attr docs.) Any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: To my knowledge tile mode is very limited in functionality and I've also never seen the functionality you describe implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6652915/969325) might be interesting to you. Basically gravity doesn't work with tilemode (as we've already established) but you could create a matrix of your images and use that to create the background of your desire. So basically build the tilemode in code yourself.